# printf char array segment fault C

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

So I have written a code that sorts words in the right order. The words are being stored via pointers and I have initialized another char array in the program to store the `char* argv`.

The last for loop is what prints segment fault and I can't figure out why.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  int i, j;
  char *key;
  char a[argc-1];
  for(i=1; i < argc; i++){
    a[i-1]= tolower(argv[i]);
      }

  for (i = 2; i < argc; i++) {
    key = argv[i];

    j = i-1;
    while (j >= 1 && strcmp(argv[j], key) > 0) {
      argv[j+1] = argv[j];
      j--;
    }

    argv[j+1] = key;
  }

  for(i = 1; i < argc; i++){
    a[i-1] = *argv[i];
  }

  for (i = 1; i < argc ; i++){
    puts(argv[i]);
  }

  for(i = 0; i < argc-1; i++){
    printf("%s", a[i]);
}
  return 0;
}
```

input

```
./a.out orange banana apple
```

output

```
apple
banana
orange
Segmentation fault
```

Comment: `tolower(argv[i])` should be rasing a warning from the compiler, otherwise it's because you did not enable them, do not ignore them at all! Warnings are very useful for expert programmers, thy must be a tool for non experts.

Comment: @iharob i commented that part out. Yet i am still getting segment fault.

Comment: Please read my answer ... let the compilation warnings guide you. I mean, try to understand the warnings and infer the way things work from that.

Comment: Can you include the actual inputs and outputs.

Comment: @matt posted in my topic a sample input and output

Comment: You are only printing/assigning the first letter. `a[i-1] = *argv[i]` only assigns the first letter of each `argv` to `a`. `a[i]` is a char so you should use `%c`

Comment: @matt then how would i store the first word in argv into a?

Comment: `char* a[argc-1]; a[i-1] = arvgv[i]`

Comment: will that also accept `tolower` without compiler error?

Comment: Did you figure out  your `tolower` issue? It works character by character, not on the whole string.

Comment: @matt not yet. I am not sure how i'll have to approach that.

Comment: You should check a reference to tolower, http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/tolower/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your compiler should also give you a warnging on:

```
printf("%s", a[i]);
```

> warning: format specifies type 'char *' but the argument has type
>         'char' [-Wformat]

If you change that to a `%c`it works *fine*.

As the warning says, when you use it `%s` printf is expecting a string or a `char*` and will treat it as such. `a[i]` is an integer type that can reference an invalid location in memory. So the correct way to do it would be to either use %c, and print a character; or use %s and pass a char* as the second argument.

Or perchance you want args in a. Change the delcaration.

```
char *a[argc-1];
```

Then change the assignment.

```
a[i-1] = argv[i];
```

Comment: Your Answer doesn't seem to explain the actual problem, it offers a Code-Fix. `If you change that to a %cit works fine.` Is not really an Answer.

Comment: @Michi it can be improved. I think the actual problem was they wanted an array of char* but instead they just had a char, so discussing the %c behavior seems a bit irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple problems in your code

1. The line `a[i - 1] = tolower(argv[i])` is wrong because `tolower()` takes `int` as paramater and you are passing `char *` so it's converting a pointer to `int` which is legal in c but does not guarantee defined behavior.
2. You are not setting the `'\0'` terminator on the `a` array which is another cause for problems, specifically when you try to use it as a string, a `char` array is not a string unless, it's a sequence of printable bytes with a terminating `'\0'` byte.
3. Allocating `argc - 1` is not going to work because

   - The value of `argc` is the number  of passed parameters to the executable.
   - If it was the length of the corresponding `argv` as found by `strlen()` you would need 1 more byte not less, so it would be `argc + 1` in any case.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using %s

```
for(i = 0; i < argc-1; i++){
printf("%s", a[i]);
```

try %c

Comment: %c would just print the first letter of each word.

Comment: Shouldn't your a be char *a[argc] rather than char a[argc]

Comment: No because argc is 4 in case of an input that 3 words. argc also counts main()

Comment: No i mean character pointer to array rather than character array.         'char *a[argc-1] '       rather than           'char a[argc-1]'       notice the pointer.

Comment: That works but my main goal to achieve from this program is to be able to take text and start words into and array and print the words alphabetically without duplicates.